# Views Block Caching issue for not logged in User

Tags: views, blocks, caching

We are using Drupal inbuilt caching with Memcache. Our website home page has more than 5 blocks created using Views for which we have enabled Time based caching. But the contents are not getting listing in these views even after the query caching time. Following is the views cache settings:
[image]

Query Caching : 15 mins and Render Caching 6 days
Block Caching : Do not Cache

Following is the Drupal cache settings:
[image]

Also, like to add one more point that the contents are published using Scheduler module.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the issue. Views Query caching and Render Caching are not related. If we set render caching higher than query caching then Drupal will always fetch from Render cache and hence the result will remains. So its recommended to set both as same values. I modified the same to 15mins Query caching and 15mins Render caching.